# ElementRef undefined for canvas

Tags: angular

First I was doing the standard javascript element from the document, but it seems like this is pretty bad practice in angular. So I opted for a different solution. The problem I am having is that my ElementRef stays undefined. I have read about using ngAfterViewInit but that did not work to resolve this. I need the actual HTMLCanvasElement to pass it to threejs, so it knows where to render the data.

```js
this.canvas = document.getElementById('threejs-canvas') as HTMLCanvasElement;
```

which I am now trying to change to

```js
export class ThreejsComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('threejs', { static: false }) threejsCanvas: ElementRef;
  canvas: HTMLCanvasElement;

  // ThreeJS properties
  perspectiveCamera: THREE.PerspectiveCamera;
  composer: Composer;
  scene: Scene;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.canvas = this.threejsCanvas.nativeElement as HTMLCanvasElement;
  }

}
```

```html
<div>
    <canvas #threejs>
        <app-threejs></app-threejs>
    </canvas>
    <app-skills></app-skills>
</div>
```

renderer class

```js
export class Renderer extends THREE.WebGLRenderer {
    constructor(threeCanvas: HTMLCanvasElement) {
        super({ canvas: threeCanvas });

        this.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
        this.setSize(threeCanvas.clientWidth, threeCanvas.clientHeight);
        this.setClearColor('#777777');
        this.shadowMap.enabled = true;
        this.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
    }
}
```

Comment: use {static: true} or move the code from ngOnInit to ngAfterViewInit

Comment: Yeah, I had already tried both those ideas, but neither of them worked.

Comment: Seems to work with both of the above suggestions. See [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xmkoxk) example.